# What to do about an unrecognized sign-in on my Google account

Tags: security, google-account

Yesterday I got an alert from Google (New sign-in alert) that someone used my password. It says a Galaxy Note 2 with an IP 106.77.169.192 signed in.

What can I do about this other than change my password (which I have done)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the right thing, if you don't know who logged in then changing your password is the best thing to do. Make sure you have a secure password, containing upper and lowercase letters and numbers and special characters, never use a name or word that's in a dictionary.

Comment: sir can i block that device if he try to login again.

Comment: no I don't think you can, but if you have a strong password, he/she will not get in.

Comment: **And never reuse your password elsewhere**. That counts especially for financial websites and sites that service as an OpenID provider (like Google, Facebook). (*Do you re-use passwords?* That could explain the break-in).

Answer (score 2):

Once you have logged back into your account and changed your password, go to this page.

[Securing your Google Account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/secureaccount)

Go through each of the steps, remove any unknown devices, or apps that have access to your account.

You can also check a log of [Security Events](https://security.google.com/settings/security/notifications) here.

I would also recommend enabling two factor security on all of your accounts; this will require a login confirmation to be confirmed by a text message token.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the other devices to log out.  You can also change your authentication to be a 2 step process.  Forcing all other devices to log out will ensure that whoever is using your account will no longer remain logged in (even if the device says keep me logged in).  Then changing the login to be a 2 step process will make your account that much more secure.  Read through this conversation.  The person on this link had the same issue as you.  I think the responder to the question in this link says it pretty clearly.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/VfV8Du3YVMM

Hope this helps